# Integration with fraction

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm having difficulty understanding how below integral is evaluated :

$$\int_0^1\frac{(1-y)^2}{2}+(1-y)y dy = \frac{-1(1-y)^3}{6}+\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{y^3}{3}\bigg|^1_0$$

What are steps involved in this evaluation ?

For $\frac{(1-y)^2}{2}$ this appears to be evaluated as  $\frac{(1-y)^{2+1}}{(3)2}$ but I'm how unsure - 1 is inserted ?

Comment: What do you call "the negative one" ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust please see question update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule,

$$((ax+b)^k)'=(ax+b)'k(ax+b)^{k-1}=ak(ax+b)^k$$

and from this,

$$\int(ax+b)^kdx=\frac{(ax+b)^{k+1}}{a(k+1)}.$$

Try with $a=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Antiderivative if $(1-y)^{2}$ is not $(1-y)^{3} /3$. If you differentiate the latter you get $-(1-y)^{2}$. Hence the antiderivative is $-(1-y)^{3} /3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
I=&\int\bigg(\frac{(1-x)^2}{2}+x(1-x)\bigg)dx\\
=&\frac12\int(1-x)^2dx+\int x(1-x)dx\\
=&\frac12\int(1-x)^2dx+\int xdx-\int x^2dx\\
\end{align}
$$
The first one:
$$I_1=\int(1-x)^2dx$$
Substitution:
$$u=1-x\Rightarrow -du=dx$$
Hence
$$I_1=-\int u^2du$$
$$I_1=-\frac{u^3}3$$
$$I_1=-\frac{(1-x)^3}3$$
Second one:
$$I_2=\int xdx=\frac{x^2}2$$
Third one:
$$I_3=\int x^2dx=\frac{x^3}3$$
Put it all together:
$$I=\frac12I_1+I_2-I_3$$
$$I=-\frac{(1-x)^3}6+\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3$$
Evaluating from $0$ to $1$ gives
$$\int_0^1\bigg(\frac{(1-x)^2}{2}+x(1-x)\bigg)dx=\frac13$$

Answer (score -1):

Remember that where $f(x)$ is linear we have that:

$$\int[f(x)]^n dx=\frac{[f(x)]^{n+1}}{(n+1)f'(x)}+C$$

Comment: I would prefer $ax+b$ instead of $f(x)$. This is misleading.

Comment: I did say where $f(x)$ is linear which implies $ax+b$

Comment: indeed, I know.

Comment: @RhysHughes As as have learned decades ago $f$ is linear iff $f(x)=ax$.  On the other hand,  $f(x)=ax+b$ is called an affine function.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe It's quite common to call the $x \mapsto ax+b$ function "linear function".

Comment: @Botond Yes, I know, but $x\mapsto ax+b$ lacks linearity ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Well, yes. I was quite sad when my analysis teacher defined the linear function that way. But I guess he is not really working with operators.